# Why can't I import nltk?

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, nltk

In windows with a 64 bit OS, once I installed nltk-2.0.4.win-amd64-py2.7.exe,from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, for my 64 bit python, I ran 'import nltk' to get the following error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from inference import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\inference\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from discourse import (ReadingCommand, CfgReadingCommand,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\inference\discourse.py", line 54, in <module>
    from nltk.sem.glue import DrtGlue
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\sem\glue.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import brown
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from reader import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.pl196x import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\pl196x.py", line 11, in <module>
    from nltk import tokenize, tree
ImportError: cannot import name tokenize
```

Suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to install it from sources, as explained [here](http://nltk.org/install.html#source-installation-for-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows)?

Comment: You're definitely using Python 2.7?
You have PyYaml installed too (and optionally, numpy)? I've just followed the instructions at [the nltk site](http://nltk.org/install.html), and I have no issues at all with importing the nltk module (python 2.7.3 on 32 bit Windows, but I can't see 64 bit making the slightest difference to the error you're experiencing).

Comment: It is very weird, it didn't happen to me in linux. One of the main reasons, I think, this happened, is because I have two pythons installed, 32 & 64 bits, and they got conflicted together that all the modules just got messed up, I tried removing one of them, but in vain, for they stay in the registry for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem as following reference link. It seems that the Python installer sometimes can't create proper registry entries in Win7 environment, users need to create them manually.

Ref link:http://www.fbagirov.com/2012/10/13/installing-nltk-for-python/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a environment variable "PYTHONPATH" with the value of my python installation path.